# How to add the Default Item (--Select--) in dropdownlist in custom popup (via html data attributes)kendo Grid in asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

am using kendo inline and popup editing in a single grid
i used custom template for popup grid 
`<script id="customPopUpTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">`
`<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">`
`<div class="k-edit-field">`
 `<input name="LoginName"  class="k-textbox"/>`
 `<span id="sta3" style="color: Red; font-size:medium;"> </span>`
  `</div><div class="div">Login Name: </div>`

```
`<div class="k-edit-field">`<br>
  `  <input name="Password" type="Password"  class="k-textbox"/> `<br>
```

`<span id="sta4" style="color: Red; font-size:medium ;"> * </span>`
    `</div> <div class="div">Password: </div>`
`<div class="k-edit-field">`
**`<input name="ScopeId"`

                `data-bind="value:ScopeId"`

                `data-value-field="ScopeId"`

                `data-text-field="ScopeName"`

        `data-source="DataSourceScopepopup"`

                `data-role="dropdownlist" /> <span id="sta6" style="color: Red; font-size:medium ;">` `</span>`**

`</div>`
   `<div class="div">Scope: </div>`

`</form>`

`var DataSourceScopepopup = new kendo.data.DataSource(`
          `{`
              `transport:`
             `{`
                  `read:`
                  `{`
                       `url: "WebServices/Project.asmx/GetScopepopup",`
                      `data: "{}",`
                       `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`
                       `type: 'POST',`
                      `dataType: 'json'`
                  `},`
                   `parameterMap: function(options, operation)`
                   `{`
                       `if (operation == 'read')`
                          `return kendo.stringify(options);`
                 `}`
                `},`
               `schema:`
                `{`
                   `data: function(Data)`
                   `{`
                       `return (Data.d);`
                   `},`
                   `model:`
                  `{`
                       `id: "ScopeName",`
                      `fields:`
                       `{`
                          `ScopeId: { type: "number"},`
                           `ScopeName: { type: "string"}`
                       `}`
                   `}`
              `},`
               `error: function(e)`
               `{`
                    `var xhr = e[0];`
                  `var statusCode = e[1];`
                   `var  errorThrown = e[2];`
   `alert('DataSourceScope - ' + xhr + ', ' + statusCode + ', ' + errorThrown);`
              `}`
          `});`

**This is My coding How to Add the Default item --Select-- in dropdownlist?
Now i get only the Database items,,, how to i add it?
thanks in Advance!!**

Comment: Can you make changes to the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attribute data-option-label="--Select--" in your template

```
 <input name="ScopeId"
    data-bind="value:ScopeId"
    data-value-field="ScopeId"
    data-text-field="ScopeName"
    data-source="DataSourceScopepopup"
    data-role="dropdownlist" 
   data-option-label="--Select--"  <!- display default value-->
    />
```

Comment: $(".k-grid-popup", grid.element).on("click", function () {
var popupWithOption = {
mode: "popup",
template: kendo.template($("#customPopUpTemplate").html()),
window: {
title: "Your Title"
}
};
grid.options.editable = popupWithOption ;
grid.addRow();
grid.options.editable = "inline";
});

This Code is Working Fine,,If i Click Edit button And Update the Record then i click add button means that 2 popup window will opened,, How to Restrict this Problem

thanks in advance..

Comment: if i click edit button after that click update that record updated successfully, then click add button means 2 windows will open,, i want to open only one window how to do ...Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759277/how-to-avoid-the-unwanted-popup-window-creation-while-using-two-types-of-editing

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a bound element, I would change either the SQL statement or the Service to add the value you want to the returned list of values.

Otherwise, you can use the databound event to add a new item to the list, something like this:

```
dataBound: function () {
if (DataSourceScopepopup.at(0). !== "--Select--") {
    DataSourceScopepopup.insert(0, { ScopeId: 0, ScopeName: "--Select--" });
}
```